# Как работает объявление пинов для Arduino?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

Писал скетч для arduino и спустя долгое время задался вопросом, каков механизм объявления аналоговых пинов arduino?

```
int InPowerOnOff = A4;
int InLight = A5;
int InPowerUp = A6;
int InPowerDown = A7;
int Out = 9;  //Шим
int light = 13;
```

Этот код работал, но как мне простили присвоение переменной типа int выражения A4 к примеру? Как это работает?

Comment: A4 объявлено так: static const uint8_t A4 = 22;
Посмотрите в папке, куда arduino установлено, много интересного узнаете:)

Answer (score 2):

Если вы откроете файл [pins_arduino.h](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/variants/standard/pins_arduino.h) (он существует в нескольких вариантах для каждого типа платы), увидите объявления этих констант:

```
#define PIN_A0   (14)
#define PIN_A1   (15)
#define PIN_A2   (16)
#define PIN_A3   (17)
#define PIN_A4   (18)
#define PIN_A5   (19)
#define PIN_A6   (20)
#define PIN_A7   (21)

static const uint8_t A0 = PIN_A0;
static const uint8_t A1 = PIN_A1;
static const uint8_t A2 = PIN_A2;
static const uint8_t A3 = PIN_A3;
static const uint8_t A4 = PIN_A4;
static const uint8_t A5 = PIN_A5;
static const uint8_t A6 = PIN_A6;
static const uint8_t A7 = PIN_A7;
```

Это просто синонимы, к аналоговым пинам можно обращаться также как к цифровым, по их номеру.

Причём сам оп себе номер ничего не значит, это просто внутреннее обозначение языка/фреймворка Arduino, далее во всех операциях с портами, такими как `digitalWrite` по номеру порта выясняется какое значение и в какой регистр контроллера нужно отправить для выполнения команды пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

По факту это просто константы, из которых потом строятся Port Flags.

Из документации (Перевод):

> D0-D7 флаги PORTD биты 0 до 7
> D8-13 флаги PORTB биты 0-5 (биты 6,7 они используются под капотом как внешний генератор частот кварц на 16Мhz)
> D14-19 флаги PORTC биты 0-5 (бит 6 не доступен, он используется под Reset; бит 7 не используется как IO ножка на всех '328 устройствах)
> D14-D19 также могут использоваться как аналоговые входы от A0 до A5. (ADC6,7 доступны как аналоговые входы только на некоторых платах для поверхностного монтажа)

Да ещё очень важно... Стоит понимать что в реальности PORTB, PORTD управляет сразу 8ю ножками. То-есть за 1 такт состояние меняется на 8 ногах одновременно. Но чтобы ученикам школ и просто хоббистам было проще они разделены и управляются через analogWrite и digitalWrite.

Если смотреть на чистую железяку без ардуино то Blink выглядел бы вот так.

Исходник blink (плюс комментарии)

```
/*
 * @file blink-led.c
 * @brief avr-gcc example blinking led
 * 
 * @date 2020-09-19
 * @license GNU GPLv3
 * @author Paweł Sobótka
 *
 */

// Выбираем частоту на которой работает камень Atmega
// Если выставить неправильно то функции которые используют
// задержки например UART, I2C, шим, _delay_ms будут безбожно глчить.

#ifndef F_CPU
#define F_CPU 4000000L
#endif

#include <avr/io.h> // Подключаем IO (для управления ногами)
#include <util/delay.h> // Подключаем delay (для _delay_ms)

// Далее просто пример формулы расчёта F_CPU от автора примера где CKDIV8 фюз
/*
 * F_CPU == 4000000 Hz
 * CKDIV8=1
 * delay = delay/8;
 * real F_CPU = 500000 Hz
 */

// Точка входа в прошивку
int main(void)
{
    // Аналог setup в arduino 
    DDRB = 0b00000001; // Настраиваем PORTB на вывод
    // Аналог loop в Arduino
    while(1)
    {
        // Подать 1 на 7й флаг PORTB
        // digitalWrite(13, 1)
        PORTB = 0b00000001;
        // Ждать 125ms
        _delay_ms(125);
        // Подать 0 на 7й флаг PORTB
        // digitalWrite(13, 0)
        PORTB = 0b00000000;
        // Ждать 125ms
        _delay_ms(125);
    }

    // По факту камень до сюда дойти некогда не должен
    return 0;
}
```